# How to pinpoint which device on home network is using upload bandwidth?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

So I noticed on my router (running DD-WRT) just now that about 500MB to 1GB was uploaded everyday on my home network for the past 5 days. The only thing I've done recently was to setup dynamic DNS so that I can access some of my devices from 3G. I can't think what would be uploading so much everyday. Usually it's MUCH less.

What's the best way to pin point where the culprit is?

I have a lotta stuff (relatively) running on my home network: QNAP NAS, Raspberry Pi, Boxee Box, Roku are the main ones. I don't do torrents so I'm a bit puzzled here.

Please assist.

Answer (score 2):

With the right version of firmware, you can run NTOP.  Details here

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Network_traffic_analysis_with_netflow_and_ntop

The Bandwidth Guide is here:  http://techowto.files.wordpress.com/2008/09/ntop-guide.pdf
and it doesn't require much hardware to run it.

[image: NTOP sample report]

Comment: Wow, not sure this is within my grasp as I'm a Linux n00b but I'll have a read through that. Anything a bit 'simpler' I could use in the interim?

Comment: Well, to really monitor, you need a monitoring tool.  I thought the DD-WRT had a page that showed bandwidth by device, but can't find a reference & no longer own one.  There are lots of references with simple instructions for installing NTOP on Linux, though, and it's free ... not sure anything else is going to be easier.  Try this page for hopefully-easier instructions: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-install-ntop-network-traffic-monitoring-software/

Comment: Do you know off hand if it's possible to install it on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: There are discussions, like here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=7427  but I have no firsthand knowledge of doing it.